# How do I crop a 3D surface in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I am attempting to reproduce the following graph using `pgfplots`:

[image: Elliptic paraboloid graph in Geogebra]

Here is the MWE code I developed, along with the corresponding plot generated:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=8cm,
            height=12cm,
            axis lines=center, 
            view={120}{30},
            mesh/interior colormap name=hot,
            colormap/cool,
            point meta min=0.5, point meta max=6,
            xmin=-2,    xmax=2,     xlabel=\Large{$s$},
            ymin=-0.5,  ymax=2.5,   ylabel=\large{$t$},
            zmin=0,     zmax=6,
        ]
        \addplot3[
            surf,
            shader=interp,
            samples=50,
            domain=-2:2, y domain=-0.5:2.5
        ]
        {14*x*x+20*x*y-22*x+11*y*y-24*y+14};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered elliptic paraboloid in pgfplots]

There are a few issues:

1. The view box does not crop the plot as I would like. I am looking for the elliptic intersection with the plane `z=6` akin to the first image.
2. The interior surface (colored by `mesh/interior colormap name=hot`) is not visible.
3. `pgfplots` is giving the following warning:

```
Package pgfplots Warning: the combination 'shader=interp,interior colormap name
' is inefficient (it uses 'shader=faceted interp,faceted color=none') and may s
low down the *display* of your document on input line 44.
```

I only know the command `shader=interp` to remove mesh gridlines and I would like to shade the interior and exterior surfaces with different colormaps.

What is going on? How can I get the desired "crop" effect? For reference, here is the surface rendered with gridlines:
[image: gridlines pgfplots graph]